# fastest way to convert C string to all one case processor wise

Tags: c, string, assembly, type-conversion, cpu-registers

The following code which I whipped up in 7 minutes takes a short string and converts all letters to lower case:

```
void tolower(char *out,const char *in){
    int l=strlen(in);int cc;int i;
    for (i=0;i<l;i++){
        cc=(int)in[i]-0;
        if (cc >=65 && cc <=90){cc+=0x20;}
        out[i]=(char)cc;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    const char *w="aBcDe";
    char w2[6]="     ";
    tolower(w2,w);
    printf("x=%s %s\n",w,w2);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The problem with it is that I will be dealing with large sets of data (approximately 10KB worth of data per second) and I want to be able to make a function that works the fastest possible.

I have seen code out there that can deal with machine registers and when I used code like that in the past with Quick Basic, things worked faster.

So I'm curious as to how I could use machine registers (like eax) compatible with both 32 and 64 bit processors in my C program.

If I could take at least 4 bytes of the string at a time and then act on all 4 bytes simultaneously, then that would be best.

In Quick Basic, I could achieve what I need with the help of its mkd$() and cvd() functions.

Anyone know how I can make the function I posted work faster? and please don't say upgrade the computer processor.

Comment: Are you really saying 10 kilobytes per second? Do you know that current processors can process gigabytes per second? The first thing to get rid of is `strlen`. Obviously scanning the string twice is not good for performance.

Comment: Why do you compute `strlen`? Do you have no other way of telling when the string is over? (Hint: what does `strlen` do?)

Comment: What does `in[i] - 0` achieve? Did you mean `((in[i] - 0) * 1 + (true ? 0 : -0))`?

Comment: 10k per second will have your cpu sitting around twiddling its thumbs for about 99.9% of the time ;-)

Comment: I would consider a name differing from [**tolower**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/tolower) for starters.

Comment: @Jester I'm aware, but I'm saying 10 kilobytes because that's about the average length of data I'm dealing with in a one-second time frame at various times. I could check for null to denote end of string but I wasn't sure if manual checking is faster than strlen.

Comment: Hmmm: To do so 4 bytes (or maybe 2 bytes) at a time: It would benefit knowing something about the nature of the input: totally random, or  usually lower case?  ASCII? Are the arrays accessible pass the end up to the next quad boundary? Processor specific?

Comment: @Mike A potential speed-up may be had if you explained _why_ converting strings to lower-case is useful.  Possible speed-up could be had leaving the strings as-is.

Comment: With MMX/SSE/AVX I believe you could convert 8, 16, or 32 characters in parallel with a couple of compares, ANDs and an XOR. Finding the end of the string would probably get a bit trickier though, so it could end up being slower than using a LUT.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to convert whole file to lowercase in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810259/best-way-to-convert-whole-file-to-lowercase-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

Two approaches, which one is faster depends on profiling in your system.

```
// tolower()
void Mike_tolower1(char *out, const char *in) {
  while ((*out++ = tolower((unsigned char) (*in++) )) != 0);
  }
}

// table lookup
void Mike_tolower2(char *out, const char *in) {
  // fill in the table
  static const char lwr[CHAR_MAX+1] = { '\0', '\1', '\2', ...
        'a', 'b' ...
        'a', 'b' ...
   };    
  while (*in) {
    *out++ = lwr[(unsigned char) (*in++)];
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't an array need a numeric index to it?

Comment: @Mike The result of `(*in++)` is a `char` which _is_ an integer type - typically 1 byte long.  Casting it to `(unsigned char)` insures its range is positive.

Comment: @chux likewise with the input to `tolower` if you want hi-ascii to have any chance whatsoever. I had that loop in my copy buffer for almost two hours and never got to post it (work, uck), so uptick.

Answer (score 1):

Fastest way don't use `strlen()` since it does exactly what the following code does, it counts how many characters are there before the `'\0'` appears so you are iterating through the string twice, do it this way

```
#include <ctype.h>

void string_tolower(char *string)
{
    while (*string != '\0')
    {
        *string = tolower(*string);
        string++;
    }
}
```

and don't call your function `tolower` it's a standard function declared in `ctype.h` and it converts a single ascii character to lower case.

Answer (score 0):

Fastest depends on the processor, but a pretty speedy version is:

```
int c;
char *cp;
for (cp = out; 0 != (c=*cp); ++cp) {
    if ((c >= 'A') && (c <= 'Z'))
        *cp = (char)(c + 'a' - 'A');
}
```

That includes Jester's suggestion of avoiding strlen.

Comment: Thank you for the source code Mike Housky and iharob, but I'm looking for a way to compare more bytes at once which is why I was looking for a machine register way of doing it. I'm gonna start playing with all these ideas and benchmark them

Comment: and @Mike, I think your code is comparing each character only to the letter A (hence if c >= 'A' and c <= 'A')?

Comment: @Mike This does use registers in the sense that the cp pointer will almost always be in a register, and the c variable can be completely optimized away because the value is only used long enough to store a modified version.  Inline assembler is unlikely to to better.

Comment: @Mike Oops on the 2nd constant.  Looks like GroovyDotCom fixed it, though.  (Thanks!)

Comment: Change *cp = (char)(c + 'a' - 'A'); by *cp = (char)(c + ('a' - 'A'));

Answer (score 0):

If you have some RAM to burn, you can compute a lookup table. So for example:

pseudocode for creating a tolower lookup table

```
lookup["AA"] = "aa"
lookup["bb"] = "bb"
```

This way you can lowercase 2 bytes at a time and with no if statements needed.

If you really want to go nuts, you could write a GPGPU implementation that would scream.

See Chux answer for an example of implementing a 1 char at a time look-up table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna use this code I just constructed now based from various sources including here: https://code.google.com/p/stringencoders/wiki/PerformanceAscii.

```
void tolower1(char *out,const char *in,int lg){
    uint32_t x;
    const uint32_t* s = (const uint32_t*) in;
    uint32_t* d = (uint32_t*) out;
    int l=(lg/sizeof(uint32_t));
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<l;++i){
        x=s[i];
        x=x-(((x+(0x05050505+0x1a1a1a1a)) >> 2) & 0x20202020);
        d[i]=x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I suggest something more like:

#include <ctype.h>


int main()
{
    const char *w="aBcDe";

    // allow room for nul termination byte
    char w2[6]="      " = {'\0'}; 

    // this 'for' statement may need tweaking if
    // w[] contains '\0' byte except at the end
    for( int i=0; w[i]; i++) 
    { 
        w3[i] = tolower(w[i]);
    }

    printf("x=%s %s\n",w,w2);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
} // end function: main


or, for a callable function,
that also allows for nul bytes within the string

char *myToLower( int byteCount, char *originalArray )
{
    char *lowerArray = NULL;

    if( NULL == (lowerArray = malloc(byteCount) ) )
    { // then, malloc failed
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    for( int i=0; i< byteCount; i++ )
    {
        lowerArray[i] = tolower(originalArray[i]);
    }

    return( lowerArray );
} // end function: myToLower
```