# Converting all strings in a txt file to lowercase in c

Tags: c, file, lowercase

I am assigned to convert all strings to lowercase in a txt file and then output it in a new txt file but i cant seem find anywhere how to do it. Any help would be very appriciated! Thank you This is what i have till now but there is the y at the end so im thinking if there is a better way to do it or if i can remove the y with the two dots on top..

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<process.h>

void main() {
   FILE *fp1, *fp2;
   char a;

   fp1 = fopen("test.txt", "r");
   if (fp1 == NULL) 
   {
      puts("cannot open this file");
      exit(1);
   }

   fp2 = fopen("test1.txt", "w");
   if (fp2 == NULL) {
      puts("Not able to open this file");
      fclose(fp1);
      exit(1);
   }

   do
   {
      a = fgetc(fp1);
      a = tolower(a);
      fputc(a, fp2);
   } while (a != EOF);

   fcloseall();
   getch();
}
```

Comment: 'i cant seem find anywhere how to do it' - really?  Please post what you have done so far to look, eg. your Google search string/s.

Comment: Read and write char by char. Forget strings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to convert whole file to lowercase in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810259/best-way-to-convert-whole-file-to-lowercase-in-c)

Comment: edited added what i have been able to find

Comment: 'while (a != EOF);' too late:(

Comment: `char a;` --> `int a;` please RTM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read input from a file, you should always check whether you get valid input before proceeding to use it. In your case, you get input in the line.

```
a = fgetc(fp1);
```

You need to check whether `a` is valid input before proceeding to use it.

```
if ( a != EOF )
{
   a = tolower(a);
   fputc(a, fp2);
}
```

Another thing to update. Don't use

```
char c;
```

Use

```
int c;
```

instead.

`char` type can be a signed type or unsigned type on your platform. If it is an unsigned type, it will never have a negative value. Hence, it will never equal `EOF`, which is `-1` often, which will lead to an infinite loop.

If you lookup the documentation of `fgetc`, you will notice that its return type is `int`, not `char`.

Your program can be updated to something like:

```
void main() {
   FILE *fp1, *fp2;
   int a;

   // Add rest of your code
   // ...

   do
   {
      a = fgetc(fp1);
      if ( a != EOF )
      {
         a = tolower(a);
         fputc(a, fp2);
      }
   } while (a != EOF);

   // Add rest of your code
   // ...
}
```

The `do-while` loop can be simplified to:

```
   while ( (a = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF )
   {
      a = tolower(a);
      fputc(a, fp2);
   }
```

Comment: Also, `tolower` and many other library functions that you might imagine would take and/or return a `char` type, use `int` type.